Android deeplinks and opening them from browsers
I have a question about deeplinks. When implementing them I found out that calling them from adb the app opens just fine. The same case is when I click on the link, for example, in notes app.
But when coping and pasting the same link into the browser bar and trying to open it, it either opens the site, or tries to navigate me to the play store.
And here is the question, does it need some kind of special handling? For example when I paste X (former twitter) link to the browser, it tries to open the app, so it is doable, the question remains how?
Edit:

Browsers checked: Firefox, Chrome, build in Samsung Internet one.
Example of my link: https://www.example.com/category/dogs
Example of 'X's link: https://x.com/autor/status/12345678765432


"the browser bar" -- there are many browsers for Android. Please be more specific about which browsers you are testing. "But when coping and pasting the same link" -- what is the link? In particular, what is the scheme of the link? "when I paste X (former twitter) link" -- what is the link? In particular, what is the scheme of the link?

@CommonsWare added things you mentioned to the question, in Edit section.

You need to set up the deep link on your website. For example
Manifest
<data android:scheme="https"
  android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
  android:pathPrefix="/my-path"

Website
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/my-path">Open App</a>

